# Proving $\int_0^{\pi } f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = n\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I've been asked to show $$
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac{2(1+\cos x) - \cos((n-1)x) - \cos((n+1)x) - 2\cos nx}{1-\cos 2x} \ dx = n\pi
$$

The integrand simplifies nicely to $$\frac{\cos nx - 1}{\cos x - 1}$$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from here, I've tried using a $x \mapsto \pi - x$ sub, but that doesn't work either. Real methods, please.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would look for some sort of symmetry.  That, or use contour integration over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm still in high school, the intended approach has nothing to do with contour integration. I'll edit that in, thanks. I was hoping it would have symmetry in $x=\pi$, but apparently not.

Comment: Perhaps there's symmetry about the line $x = \pi/2$? Or perhaps that's what you meant.

Comment: Would symmetry in $x=\pi/2$ help given the limits?

Comment: For example: if shifting the graph $\pi/2$ to the left makes the function odd, then that would help.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:
Observe that
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\cos nx−1}{\cos x−1}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2(nx/2)}{\sin^2(x/2)}\mathrm{d}x
$$
and then you can follow [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/114036/103399).

Comment: I'm guessing that in a High School calc class, the student is not looking for Fourier analysis and Perseval's identity any more than he is looking for contour integration.

Comment: @MarkFischler perhaps not, but the recursion-based method looks very much like what was intended, especially given how the problem was presented.

Comment: There isn't Fourier analysis...just trigonometry and if you follow the link just a recursion formula...