# A sine integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, trigonometric-series

The integral
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{ \sin(n\theta) }{ \sin(\theta) } \ d\theta
\end{align}
is claimed to not have a closed form expression. In this view find the series solution of the integral as a series involving of $n$.

**Editorial note**: 
As described in the problem several series may be obtained, of which, all seem to hold validity. As a particular case, from notes that were made a long while ago, the formula
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{ \sin(n\theta) }{ \sin(\theta) } \ d\theta = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{r-1} \ \ln\left(\frac{2r+1}{2r-1}\right) \ \sin(r n \pi)
\end{align}
is stated, but left unproved. Can this formula be proven along with finding other series dependent upon $n$?

Comment: It is $\pm\dfrac\pi2$ for odd values of *n*, depending on the sign of *n*.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113728/computing-int-02-pi-frac-sinnx-sinx-mathrm-dx

Comment: @Jika Nice work on finding an older example to reconsider, however the problem posted above is seeking different limits and a different form than that posted in the link you have provided.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to mention it to you so maybe it is helpful. @Leucippus

Comment: I added the integration tag since it's followed by more people than than the definite-integrals tag.

Comment: The formula in the editorial note doesn't sound right. If both $r$ and $n$ are integers, the factor $\sin(rn\pi)$ is always zero???

Comment: @achille Since $r$ is an integer in the summation it would be natural for the case of $n$ being integer for the expression $sin(r n \pi)$ to be zero. As the problem has no restrictions it then suggests that $n$ need not be an integer. As several nice solutions have been discovered for even and odd values of $n$ then the case of $n$ not being an integer remains open.

Comment: @Leucippus If the equation is correct, then one should be able to recover the known result for integer $n$. It is sort of a surprise naive application of that formula give us $0$.

Answer (score 5):

In the case that $n=2k$ is an even positive integer we have the identity $$\frac{\sin 2kx}{\sin x} = 2 \cos(2k-1)x + 2 \cos(2k-3)x + \ldots + 2 \cos x.$$

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \frac{\sin 2kx}{\sin x} \ dx &= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \Big(\cos x + \cos 3x + \ldots + \cos(2k-1) \ x \Big) \ dx \\  &= 2 \left(\sin x + \frac{1}{3} \sin 3x + \ldots + \frac{1}{2k-1} \sin(2k-1) x \right)\Bigg|^{\pi/2}_{0} \\ &= 2 \left(1- \frac{1}{3} + \ldots + \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1} \right).  \end{align}$$

**EDIT**:

To prove that $$ \frac{\sin 2kx}{\sin x} = 2 \cos(2k-1)x + 2 \cos(2k-3)x + \ldots + 2 \cos x,$$ notice that

$$\begin{align} \frac{\sin kx}{\sin x} &= \frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} \frac{e^{-ix}}{e^{-ix}} \\ &= \frac{e^{i(k-1)x} - e^{i(-k-1)x}}{1-e^{-2ix}}  \\ &= e^{i(k-1)x} \frac{1-e^{-2ikx}}{1-e^{-2ix}} \\ &= e^{i(k-1)x} \left(1 + e^{-2ix} + e^{-4ix} + \ldots + e^{-2i(k-1)x} \right) \\ &= e^{i(k-1)x} + e^{i(k-3)x} + \ldots + e^{i(-k+1)x}. \end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$ \frac{\sin 2kx}{\sin x} = e^{i(2k-1)x} + e^{i(2k-3)x} + \ldots + e^{ix} + e^{-ix} + \ldots + e^{i(-2k+1)x}$$

$$ = 2 \cos(2k-1)x + 2 \cos(2k-3)x + \ldots + 2 \cos x.$$

Comment: Nice work and does express the intent of the problem proposed. The demonstration of the solution proposed is appreciated in view of a learning experience.

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks.

Comment: Very Nice Boss @RandomVariable +1

Comment: @Integrals Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U_n(x)$ be the [Chebyshev's polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition) of the second kind. We know

$$U_{n}(\cos\theta) = \frac{\sin(n+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}$$
and it has a generating function of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty U_n(x)t^n = \frac{1}{1-2xt+t^2}$$
Substitute $x$ by $\cos\theta$ in above expression, integrate $\theta$ over $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and uses a relatively easy to prove identity

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\theta}{K - \cos\theta} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{K^2-1}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{K+1}{K-1}}\quad\text{ for }\quad K > 1$$
We have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} U_n(\cos\theta)d\theta
&= \frac{1}{2t}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{\frac{1+t^2}{2t} - \cos\theta}\\
&= \frac{1}{2t}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2t}\right)^2-1}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{\frac{1+t^2}{2t}+1}{\frac{1+t^2}{2t}-1}}\\
&= \frac{2}{1-t^2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)\\
&= \frac{2}{1-t^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \tan^{-1} t\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{1-t^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k t^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Compare the coefficients of both sides, we get

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta}d\theta
= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} U_n(\cos\theta)d\theta 
= \begin{cases} 
\frac{\pi}{2},& n = 2k\\
\displaystyle\;2\sum\limits_{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1},& n = 2k+1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice solution and method.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{I_{n}\equiv
    \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin\pars{n\theta} \over \sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta:
    \ {\large ?}}$

> Since $\ds{I_{n} = -I_{-n}}$, we'll study the case $\ds{n > 0}$:
>   \begin{align}
> I_{n\ >\ 0}&=\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\expo{\ic n\theta} - 1\over \sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> =\Im
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop {\phantom{\Huge A}0\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ \pi/2}}
> {z^{n} - 1 \over \pars{z^{2} - 1}/\pars{2\ic z}}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
> \\[3mm]&=2\,\Im
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop {\phantom{\Huge A}0\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ \pi/2}}
> {1 - z^{n} \over -z^{2} + 1}\,\dd z
> \\[3mm]&=2\,\Im\bracks{%
> -\int_{1}^{0}{1 - \expo{\ic\pi n/2}y^{n} \over y^{2} + 1}\,\ic\,\dd y
> -\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n} \over -x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}
> =2\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{1 - \expo{\ic\pi n/2}y^{n} \over y^{2} + 1}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=\underbrace{2\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over y^{2} + 1}}
> _{\ds{=\ {\pi \over 2}}}\ -\
> 2\cos\pars{n\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{y^{n}\,\dd y \over y^{2} + 1}
> \end{align}

$$
I_{n\ >\ 0}={\pi \over 2}
-2\cos\pars{n\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{y^{n}\,\dd y \over y^{2} + 1}
\,,\qquad\qquad I_{n\ <\ 0} = -I_{-n}
$$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}{y^{n}\,\dd y \over y^{2} + 1}}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\pars{n + 1}t} \over 1 + \expo{-2t}}\,\dd t
> =\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{\ell}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{2\ell + n + 1}t}\,\dd t
> =\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\ell} \over 2\ell + n + 1}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\bracks{\Psi\pars{n + 3 \over 4} - \Psi\pars{n + 1 \over 4}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm)
>   ${\bf\mbox{6.3.1}}$.

$$\color{#44f}{%
I_{n}=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
-I_{-n} & \mbox{if} & n < 0
\\[1mm]
0 & \mbox{if} & n = 0
\\[3mm]
\color{#c00000}{\left.\begin{array}{lcl}
{\pi \over 2} & \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is odd}
\\
{\pi \over 2} - \half\,\pars{-1}^{n/2}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{n + 3 \over 4} - \Psi\pars{n + 1 \over 4}}
& \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is even}
\end{array}\right\rbrace} & \mbox{if} & n > 0
\end{array}\right.}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin\theta}d\theta$$

---

Case i): When $n$ is odd i.e $n=2k+1$.
$$I_{2k+1}-I_{2k+3}=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin((2k+1)\theta)-\sin((2k+3)\theta)}{\sin\theta}d\theta=-2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(2(k+1)\theta)\,d\theta$$
$$\Rightarrow I_{2k+1}-I_{2k+3}=0 \Rightarrow I_{2k+3}=I_{2k+1}=\cdots=I_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
i.e whenever $n$ is odd, the value of the integral is always $\pi/2$

---

Case ii): When $n$ is even i.e $n=2k$.
$$I_{2k}-I_{2k+2}=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(2k\theta)-\sin((2k+2)\theta)}{\sin\theta}d\theta=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos((2k+1)\theta)d\theta$$
$$\Rightarrow I_{2k}-I_{2k+2}=\frac{(-1)^k2}{2k+1} \Rightarrow I_n-I_{n+2}=\frac{2i^n}{n+1}$$
And I doubt the above recursive relation has a nice solution. :P