# How to evaluate the integral $ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin{nx}\cos{nx}}{\sin{x}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Would someone give me a hint or a solution ?

How to  evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin{nx}\cos{nx}}{\sin{x}}\mathrm dx$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113728/computing-int-02-pi-frac-sinnx-sinx-mathrm-dx, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508101/determine-the-anti-derivative-of-frac-sinnx-sinx-where-n-is-an-eve.

Answer (score 7):

Such integral is just zero, because, given that:
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(2n x)}{\sin(x)}, $$
we have:
$$ f(x)+f(x+\pi) = 0, $$
so:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
  \sin nx \times \cos nx &= \frac{1}{2} \, \sin 2nx \\
  I_n &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin 2nx}{2\sin x} \, dx
\end{align*}$$

Now try to solve the recursive formula, integration by parts:

$$I_{n}=\frac{-\cos 2nx}{2n \sin x}
- \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{-\cos 2nx}{4n} \times \frac{-\cos x}{\sin^2 x} \, dx $$

(for the domain $0$ to $2\pi$)

Comment: thanks for @darya khosrotash ,you can go on ?