# Evaluate the definite integral $\frac{105}{19}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin 8x}{\sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

> Determine the value of $$\frac{105}{19}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin 8x}{\sin x}\ \text dx$$

My approach: using $\int^a_0f(x)\ \text dx = \int^a_0 f(a-x)\ \text dx$,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{105}{19}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin 8x}{\sin x}\ \text dx &= \frac{105}{19}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sin (4\pi -8x)}{\cos x}\ \text dx\\
&= \frac{105}{19}\int^{\pi/2}_0 -\frac{\sin 8x}{\cos x}\ \text dx
\end{align}
$$

But it seems it won't work please help thanks

Comment: With the help of Wolfram, the answer is 8.

Comment: i have also the answer $8$ without WolframAlpha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using formulas $\sin2a = 2\sin a\cos a,\quad \cos a \cos b = \frac12(\cos(a+b)-\cos(a-b))$, have:
$$\dfrac{\sin 8x}{\sin x} = 8\cos 4x\cos 2x\cos x = 4\cos4x(\cos3x+\cos x) = 2(\cos7x+\cos 5x+\cos 3x +\cos x),$$so

\begin{align}
\dfrac {105}{19}\int_0^\limits\dfrac\pi2\dfrac{\sin 8x}{\sin x} &= \dfrac {210}{19}\int_0^\limits\dfrac\pi2(\cos7x+\cos 5x+\cos 3x +\cos x)\,dx =\\
&= \dfrac {210}{19}\left(\frac17\sin7x+\frac15\sin 5x+\frac13\sin 3x +\sin x\right)\biggr|_0^\frac\pi2 =
\\&= \frac{210}{19}\left(-\frac17+\frac15-\frac13+1\right) = \frac{210}{19}\cdot\frac{76}{105} = 8.
\end{align}

Comment: The arithmetic is wrong.  $$\frac{210}{19}\left(\frac17+\frac15+\frac1e+1\right)=\frac{352}{19}\ne 18$$

Comment: The final result is wrong, due to sign errors, and the last line should read $$\frac{210}{19}\left(-\frac17+\frac15-\frac13+1\right) = 8.$$

Comment: @Did You startled by signs

Comment: What? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: $+\dfrac17.$ Be careful when criticizing

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Hi there. :) I made the same mistake as yours. You will find out your mistake if you take a look at my answer. In fact, $\sin (2k-1) \frac{\pi}{2} = (-1)^{k+1}$.

Comment: @Did Is [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Climits_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%7B8x%7D%7D%7B%5Csin+x%7Ddx) an argument for you?

Comment: @H. R.  Hi :) There is not any error now. I'd verify my solution

Comment: To indicate that $+\frac17$ should read $-\frac17$, as explained in my comment (and that $+\frac13$ should read $-\frac13$)? Well, indirectly, yes, the numerical value that WA provides would be an argument for that. Once again, I fail to see your point. ("I'd verify my solution": You did? Really?)

Comment: Last try: What is $\sin(7x)$ at $x=\pi/2$, already?

Comment: @Did It was successful, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Method $1$**

$1.$ Use the identity

$$2\sin x \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(2k-1)x = \sin2nx$$

which can easily be verified by using

$$2\sin x \cos(2k-1)x = \sin 2k x - \sin 2(k-1) x$$

and the **telescoping property** of the sums.

$2.$ Use the above formula to get

$$\frac{\sin 2nx}{\sin x} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(2k-1)x$$

$3.$ Integrate to obtain

$$\begin{align}
F(x) &=\int \frac{\sin 2nx}{\sin x} \, dx \\
&= 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int \cos(2k-1)x \, dx \\
&= 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k-1} \sin(2k-1)x + C
\end{align}$$

$4.$ Evaluating the definite integral results in harmonic partial sums

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin 2nx}{\sin x} \\
&= F(\frac{\pi}{2})-F(0)\\
&= 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin (2k-1) \frac{\pi}{2}}{2k-1} - 0\\
&= \boxed{2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}}
\end{align}$$

In your case, you may choose $n=4$.

Comment: Or the 7th Chebyshev polynomial of the 2nd kind.  6 of one, half-dozen of the other I guess.

Comment: @RonGordon: Yeah, Thanks for mentioning that. :)

Comment: @HR, how to finish it from here?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: It seems that I should add one more hint. :) The answer is the substitution $\sin(x)=u$

Comment: This makes the same sign error as the currently accepted answer, the correct final result being $$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin 2nx}{\sin x} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}.$$

Comment: @Did: Yes! You are right. Thanks for mentioning that. :) I fixed the error.

Comment: I think the errors are due to the rush to publish before others a solution. I have many times solutions but (because of my deficient English) when I finish, there are many solutions already, some of them so equal to mines that I prefer not to publish. (Because of the rush I have had a lot of mistakes)

Comment: @Piquito: Yeah! :D It is a reason. :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin nx}{\sin x}dx$

Using Prosthaphaeresis Formulas,

$$I_{m+2}-I_m=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(m+1)x\ dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Using approaches from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113728/computing-int-02-pi-frac-sinnx-sinx-mathrm-dx) it seems to be that

$$\int \frac{\sin(8x)}{\sin{x}}\mathrm{d}x=2\sin(x)+\frac{2}{3}\sin(3x)+\frac{2}{5}\sin(5x)+\frac{2}{7}\sin(7x)+C$$

Then doing the calculus for your integral we get $152/105$ so the answer is $8$.

Answer (score 1):

**Method $2$**

Here are hints to another approach.

$1.$ You can observe from the [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Formulae_for_cosine_and_sine_individually) that

$$\sin (8x) = 128\sin \left( x \right)\cos^7 {\left( x \right)} - 192\sin \left( x \right)\cos^5 {\left( x \right)} + 80\sin \left( x \right)\cos^3 {\left( x \right)} - 8\sin \left( x \right)\cos \left( x \right)$$

and hence

$$\frac{\sin(8x)}{\sin(x)}=128 \cos^7 {\left( x \right)} - 192 \cos^5 {\left( x \right)} + 80\cos^3 {\left( x \right)} - 8\cos \left( x \right)$$

$2.$ Next use this trick

$$\begin{align}
\cos^7 x= \cos^6 x \cos x = (1-\sin^2 x)^3 \cos x \\
\cos^5 x= \cos^4 x \cos x = (1-\sin^2 x)^2 \cos x \\
\cos^3 x= \cos^2 x \cos x = (1-\sin^2 x)^1 \cos x
\end{align}$$

$3.$ Finally, use the substitution

$$\sin x = u$$